# MySql Date read incorrectly using getDate

Tags: java, mysql

I have two date fields in my mysql db.

They look like so in my db.

[image]

When I pull them into java using resultSet.getDate I get the following dates in java...

```
29/01/2016 00:00:00,3/01/2016 00:00:00
```

My mapping code is below...

```
masterList.setRpmPromoCompDetailStartDate(resultSet.getDate(DaoConstants.COLUMN_HEADER_RPM_PROMO_COMP_DETAIL_START_DATE));
masterList.setRpmPromoCompDetailEndDate(resultSet.getDate(DaoConstants.COLUMN_HEADER_RPM_PROMO_COMP_DETAIL_END_DATE));
```

Where my domain object looks like this...

```
public class MasterList {

    private Date rpmPromoCompDetailStartDate;
    private Date rpmPromoCompDetailEndDate;
```

Everything in the output looks right except the month. Can anyone give me some advice on what might be wrong?

thanks

---

### EDIT

Here is my attempted fix...

```
            Timestamp startDateTs = resultSet.getTimestamp(DaoConstants.COLUMN_HEADER_RPM_PROMO_COMP_DETAIL_START_DATE);
            java.util.Date startDate = null;
            if (startDateTs != null){
                startDate = new java.util.Date(startDateTs.getTime());
            }
            masterList.setRpmPromoCompDetailStartDate(startDate);

            Timestamp endDateTs = resultSet.getTimestamp(DaoConstants.COLUMN_HEADER_RPM_PROMO_COMP_DETAIL_END_DATE);
            java.util.Date endDate = null;
            if (endDateTs != null){
                endDate = new java.util.Date(endDateTs.getTime());
            }
```

Comment: Show some actual JAVA code to explain what you are doing

Comment: added. Sorry I just thought getDate was all that I was doing so maybe it wasn't worth adding.

Comment: Did you confuse 'java.sql.Date' and 'java.util.Date'? Are you using a string to convert? Please provide more code.

Comment: Could you dump the table definition `DESCRIBE <tablename>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use resultset.getTimeStamp to get date

```
 java.util.Date date;
 Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp(i);
 if (timestamp != null)
 date = new java.util.Date(timestamp.getTime()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Tried that and it did not work. I got the same result

Comment: The class java.sql.Date is designed to carry only a date without time, so the conversion result you see is correct for this type. You need to use a java.sql.Timestamp to get a full date with time.
Try below:-
java.util.Date newDate = result.getTimestamp("VALUEDATE");

Comment: Hi. I've had a few reads of your comment and I don't think I am doing anything different to what you are suggesting. I've modified my post with the edited code so that you can verify i am not missing anything. thanks

Comment: I've made a terrible mistake. When inserting into db I was doing it incorrectly. this was causing the date to come out incorrectly. Sorry about this. Thanks for helping me through the problem.